# Return any words beginning with space+ specified letters + a number

Tags: r, regex, string, extract, stringr

How can I return only words matching the pattern of beginning with a **space** + **"t" or "r"** directly followed by **any number including negative numbers or decimals** in R and returning NA where any of these conditions are not met?

---

**Edit** including possible decimal numbers

For example:

```
testvec <- c("random stuff here","words 10293","random t101rando 101 000","r10000","stuff i-10283","word1 t-12.34 stuff rand10293","random100 u-1000"," r10.0 x ","test x-2930"," T r.1234567","testword120num")
```

Desired result using test data above (testvec):

```
desired_result <- c(NA,NA,"t101rando",NA,NA,"t-12.34",NA,"r10.0",NA,"r.1234567",NA)
```

Comment: `t-` or `r-` is not *directly followed by a number*.

Comment: I would like to include negative numbers so it would be

Comment: Does *including decimal number* mean to match also `t.2` or `t-.2`?

Comment: yes including t.2 or t-.2 let me add that case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
regmatches(testvec, regexpr("(?<= )[tr]-?\\.?\\d\\S*", testvec, perl=TRUE), TRUE) <- ""
testvec
# [1] ""          ""          "t101rando" ""          ""          "t-12.34"  
# [7] ""          "r10.0"     ""          "r.1234567" ""
```

having `""` instead of `NA`.